# Apache 2.0 vs Apache 2.2 and PHP - what difference do I need to know about?

Tags: php, apache-2.2

We have a production server that is running Apache 2.0 and our admins are trying to move us to a development server that is running Apache 2.2.

We need to know what kind of impact, if any, this may have for PHP development.

I know we *should* be matching our production environment as closely as possible, but I need to give some explanation to our admins as opposed to a directive.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please read the [announcement](http://www.apache.org/dist/httpd/Announcement2.2.html) or the [CHANGELOG](http://www.fightrice.com/mirrors/apache/httpd/CHANGES_2.2), and determine whether either is useful when communicating with your [INTJ-type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INTJ) admins.

As far as PHP development goes, you may re-use the version of PHP currently in use on your production server, if you are concerned about application portability.  Although, while you're at it, you may want to upgrade PHP to [the latest stable release](http://php.net/downloads.php) of the major version you are using in production, if only for security purposes.